# Facebook integration with Xamarin.Social

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.ios

I'm currently evaluating different alternatives to integrate my iOS app with Facebook. Since I'll be porting the app to Android later, [Xamarin.Social](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social/) seems like an interesting alternative. However, the documentation is a little sparse, and judging by the amount and relevance of my Google searches, there doesn't seem to be a lot of experience with it.

From what I have gathered so far, it seems that Xamarin.Social, and [Xamarin.Auth](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth/) which it depends on, have it's own `AccountStore` for storing Facebook (and other social services) accounts that integrates with the iOS KeyChain, which leads me to my qestions:

- Is the Xamarin.Social `AccountStore` and the native `ACAccountStore` integrated in any way? Or does it even wrap all of the native Facebook APIs?
- From what I've read, the native Facebook APIs handle re-authentication when an access token is expired. So if you can access an account in the ACAccountStore, you don't need to worry about it. Does Xamarin.Social also handle refresh of access tokens, or does this need to be handled manually?
- I'm not going to use any of the compose views. I just need the access token of the Facebook account, and my server will do the rest of the Facebook integration. Based on this, should I be looking at other APIs instead? Are the full Facebook APIs overkill for my usage?

**Edit:**

Another question. What use had the `RedirectUrl` property of the `FacebookService`, if I'm using `GetAuthenticationUI` to present the login view?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it for a while, here are my findings:

- It does not share accounts with the native Facebook/Twitter integration
- It does provide means to authenticate if you have no account, and you attempt to invoke the *share UI*. I have not been able to test this for expired tokens yet, but I assume it will handle this as well.

Unfortunately, the UI looks terrible compared to the native UI. But it does work, so if the looks is not that important, it seems like a viable cross platform alternative.

**Update**

Later versions have a `Twitter5Service` that integrates with the iOS Social Framework. But none of the other services uses any native authentication and share UIs.

Comment: Could you tell me what is RedirectUrl about? What have you find on your investigations? Official guide is so incomplete :( I tried different URL for this and always have unpredictable results. For example URL to my iTunes app works fine in emulator but in the real device it opens the itunes page. The only I want is to push user's timeline from the application.

Comment: I'm not sure, actually, but I think it's just an URL that the framework redirects to when it has authenticated. Within the App, it doesn't appear to be used, but you could use it to e.g. invoke some service in your backend when the authorization has completed.

Answer (score 0):

ACAccountStore is wrapped on top of Account, so yes,

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth.iOS/ACAccountWrapper.cs

You will see it stores 3 keys, Username, Expires and Token value.

Comment: Only the Twitter5Service seems to use the native iOS social framework under the hood.